# How to detect drag end in View React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a View. In this view I have a flat list that has the `onScrollEndDrag` and `onScrollBeginDrag` logic that works, except when the drag released on the bottom tab menu that is not part of the FlatList.
Because the handler is on the FlatList I can't detect drag releases that happen on the bottom tabs.
I need to have the drag end logic to be attatched to the view instead of the FlatList. How can I detect a when drag ends/the user releases the hand of the screen in the View instead of the FlatList?

Here is what I have currently:

```
 <View>
      <StatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} />
      <FlatList
        data={challenges}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <ChallengePost challenge={item} isVideoPlaying={index === currentlyPlaying && !navigatedOutOfScreen} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(challenge) => challenge._id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("window").height}
        snapToAlignment={"start"}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        onScrollEndDrag={() => (scrollEnded.current = true)}
        onScrollBeginDrag={() => (scrollEnded.current = false)}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
```

as you can see the `onScrollEndDrag` `onScrollBeginDrag` happends on the FlatList level and I want it be able to detect drag releases that happen on the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library it should help you make it easier because it wraps some of the components in its own pan gesture handlers

[react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler)

[examples](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/tree/master/examples/Example/src)

Comment: can answer my question please specifically?